# Calling webservice via server causes java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol

Tags: java, web-services, url

I am writing a web-service, which parses an xml file. In the client, I read the whole content of the xml into a String then I give it to the web-service.

If I run my web-service with main as a Java-Application (for tests) there is no problem, no error messages. However when I try to call it via the server, I get the following error:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol
```

I use the same xml file, the same code (without main), and I just cannot figure out, what the cause of the error can be.

here is my code:

```
DOMParser parser=new DOMParser();
try {
    parser.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", true);
    parser.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/schema",true);
    parser.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/dynamic",true);
    parser.setErrorHandler(new myErrorHandler());
    parser.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlFile)));
    document=parser.getDocument();
```

xmlFile is constructed in the client so:

```
String myFile ="C:/test.xml";
File file=new File(myFile);
String myString="";
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(file);
BufferedInputStream bis=new BufferedInputStream(fis);
DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(bis);

while (dis.available()!=0) {
    myString=myString+dis.readLine();
}

fis.close();
bis.close();
dis.close();
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you show us the xml file - or at least the beginning - it could have URLs for its schema and DTD

Comment: Tell us where xmlFile is constructed.

Comment: my xml file is:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<user xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="test.xmls">   
 <id>123456</id>
 <common>
  <gender>female</gender>
  <city>New York</city>
  <salary>1200</salary>
  <currency>USD</currency>
  <language>eng</language>
  <marital_status>s</marital_status>
  <children>4</children>
 </common>
 <interest>
   <category>books</category>
   <name>the lord of the rings</name>
 </interest>
</user>

Comment: Please post stacktrace and please edit original question with answers on comments instead of posting code in comments.

Comment: Ok, sorry, but the xml could not have been seen in my code as an xml. To answer to your first suggestion no other stacktrace is available. This is all, and my xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Add the protocol (http) to your xmlns:
`<user xmlns:xsi="http://w3.org...etc"`

Comment: I do not understand why it is not there, but originally it is in my xml file. Sorry.